# Unable to create dev https certificate with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am unable to generate a valid dev localhost certificate for .NET Core.

When I run the `dotnet dev-certs https -c -v` command, I get the result `No valid certificate found.` When I subsequently run `dotnet dev-certs https -v` I get the message `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.`

These messages seem to be conflicting. When I try to run a project using the localhost dev cert, I get the [expected] error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Also, as an addition validation that things don’t seem to be working right, when I check my Keychain after running `dotnet dev-certs https` & `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, no certificate is generated and/or placed in the Keychain.

Any thoughts on the cause of this? It seems from the command outputs that the CLI is writing to one location (unknown) where it thinks it already exists, but trying to read from another (active Keychain) where it is unable to find it.

Comment: How did you use localhost dev cert? Do you configure the cert manually in your code? Share us how you create .net core project.

Comment: The *only* thing you should run is `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. That will both create the local cert *and* add it to the trust store. However, the installation into the trust store must be confirmed. If you don't get a box asking if you want to actually do this popped, and/or you don't allow that, then it obviously will not be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up recreating my macOS keychain and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I went to tools> nuget package manager > package manager console
copy pasted 'dotnet dev-certs https'  and pressed enter. it worked fine thereafter